# Accessing nested json array in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to get first object from the nested json in angular2. Can any one help me in fetching first json object.
Sample Json:

```
var Datalist = [{"id":1,"status":"completed"},{"id":2,"status":"Not completed"},{"id":3,"status":"Not completed"}]
```

My angular code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li *ngFor="let c of Datalist"
    class="list-group-item">
    <label> {{c.status}} </label>
         <span class="pull-right">{{c.id}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now i am getting all 3 id's and status's. I just want first object,`1,completed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use **`ngFor`** if you need only the **`first item`**, access the first element using **`0th`** index

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li  class="list-group-item">
    <label> {{Datalist[0].status}} </label>
    <span class="pull-right">{{Datalist[0].id}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item">
    <label> {{Datalist[0].status}} </label>
         <span class="pull-right">{{Datalist[0].id}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to test if the status is completed or not , using `ngIf` directive :

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li *ngFor="let c of Datalist"
    class="list-group-item">
    <label *ngIf="c.status==='completed'"> {{c.status}} </label>
    <span class="pull-right" *ngIf="c.status==='completed'">{{c.id}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <span *ngFor="let c of Datalist; let i = index; ">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngIf="i == 0">
            <label> {{c.status}} </label>
            <span class="pull-right">{{c.id}}</span>
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
```